# How does Medicine (or Mechanics for AIs) function on Unconscious mercenaries?

Tags: planet-mercenary

The section on Dying states that:

> All damage that you suffer lowers your Health,
>   and when your Health drops to zero or below,
>   you immediately fall unconscious. The next
>   attack that hits you will kill you.

The section on Medicine states:

> The Target Number to heal a character is
>   always 15. With success, the character regains
>   1 Health, plus the amount by which you beat
>   the TN.
>
> *Example: If your result (ranks
>   + dice roll) equals 19, then the
>   patient regains 5 Health (19 - 15
>   = 4; 1 Health + 4 = 5 Health)*
>
> You can also use Medicine
>   to save a dying character. The
>   TN for this check is 20. If you
>   can reach a character within one
>   round of them dying — that is,
>   within one round of them taking a
>   hit after they fall unconscious —
>   you can make a Medicine check
>   to save their life. With success,
>   you revive the character with a
>   single point of their Health
>   remaining...

When a mercenary is knocked unconscious, does the Medicine check work by healing you by 1+margin, and going above 0 renders you conscious? Or does it work like stabilizing a dying person where you're restored to 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer**:

There's no negative Health in Planet Mercenary. There are two states you can be in if you've been reduced to 0 Health.

1. If you're at 0, and you get shot again, you are *dying*.
2. Otherwise, if you're at 0, you're *unconscious.*

When a merc is *unconscious*, use the First Aid rules (TN 15, 1+Margin over 15, or roll -14 if you prefer.)

If the merc is *dying*, you use the TN 20 rules.

**Source**: I wrote the rules.

Comment: *Ex cathedra* ruling received!

Answer (score 0):

Until I receive an official ruling *ex cathedra* from Alan Bahr, my plan is to take the better of both worlds. With a mercenary unconscious from damage, the player rolls Medicine and adds *check*-14 to the target Sophont's Health as per battlefield first-aid. If their result was 20 or greater, and the Sophont's Health is still at 0 or below, it gets adjusted to 1 as per stabilizing a Dying individual.

Unconsciousness from other sources (such as getting hit with a stun-gun) will have the Medicine check against the original DC of the effect. Otherwise, Sophonts recover at the end of an encounter (possibly in enemy captivity).